# MAMP 3.x ImageMagick convert +profile '*' test on OSX 10.9.5 runs out of memory

Tags: imagemagick, mamp, mamp-pro

The new MAMP 3.0.7.3 brings ImageMagick. My phpinfo:

[image]

Does this seems correct for you?
In my local Typo3 there are some image tests you can run. The path I gave for the Image Magick is:
    /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/

Googling indicated me that there might be an issue with the envvars. I tried to rename this in _envvars and to comment out the lines in it etc. My Imagetest Convert image formats to jpg fails. I have to force-reboot my Mac after running the test.

A simple test from command line works:

`/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/convert test.png test.jpg`

**Failing test:**
    Adding the +profile '*' to the test is failing -> running out of memory:
`/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/convert +profile '*' test.png test.jpg`

Any Idea why the tests are not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem using TYPO3 and ImageMagick, here is my setup:

TYPO3 Version 6.2.9
MAMP: Version 3.0.7.3
OSX: 10.9.5

This was my solution:

Log in to TYPO3 Install tool and set:

[GFX][imagefile_ext] = gif,jpg,jpeg,png
[GFX][im_stripProfileCommand] = -strip
[GFX][im_path] = /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/
[GFX][im_path_lzw] = /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/

The image test in the TYPO3 install tool should now work.

The problem seems to be with 'convert' trying to call X11 libraries when it raises an error. 
X11 is not installed on Macs by default so the call goes into an infinite loop hence running out of application memory.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yeah, great. That work's with Mac OSX 10.10.5 and TYPO3 6.2.13. Thanks!